# how do I return when the method header looks like this?

Tags: java, methods

Just a heads up, this is for a class. I'll present everything that I have figured out/finished thus far.

I was given a method header, but I have to write the entire method. Here is the header:

```
public static double[] solveQuadraticEquation(double a, double b, double c){
```

As you can probably guess, I just had to write a few simple lines that solved for x using the quadratic equation. Easy enough. What I'm confused about is the [] after double. I'm assuming that means the return type is a double array? How would I write that? I have two double values that I want to return, value1 and value2. Normally I would return them like:

```
return value1;
return value2;
```

How would it be different in this scenario? When I try returning the two value the way I normally would, I get the error "required: double[], found: double".

---

EDIT: I'm an idiot. I just had to put the two values into an array. I'm guessing the reason this didn't immediately come to mind is because it seems unnecessary being an array anyways.

Answer (score 1):

```
return value1;
return value2;
```

That doesn't work, because once the code hits one `return` statement, that's it, your method is done.

The thing that follows `return` has to be of the type specified in the method signature. For example, if the method signature specifies that the return type is `double[]`, an array of `double`s, every time you include a `return` statement, it has to be like

```
return array;
```

where `array` is a double array. It can either be a variable of type `double[]`, i.e. a `double` array declared earlier in the method, or it can be some expression that returns a `double` array, such as

```
return new double[] {value1, value2};
```

as [pstanton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18564655/56541) includes.

Similarly, if the method signature specifies that the return type is, say, `HashMap<Integer, String>`, every time you write a `return` statement, the word `return` has to be followed by something that evaluates to a `HashMap<Integer, String>` instance.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm confused about is the [] after double. I'm assuming that means the return type is a double array?

Yes double[] means your method is supposed to return a double array.

A method can only have a single return statement, thus you can't return the 2 values you want the way you did, instead you should try something like :

```
return new double[]{value1, value2}
```

and later access your variables like :

```
double[] result = solveQuadraticEquation(a,b,c)
//result[0] now containts value1 and result[1] contains value2
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be aware that double is different from double [], the former is a premises datatype while the later one is an array.

what I would suggest you to do is create a new array 
    double [] root = new double [2];
and assign the two roots to root [0] and root [1] respectively. then return that array.